# Creating a Keras Callback that activates every n epochs

Tags: python, callback, keras

I want to create my own Callback in Keras but don't really understand how to do it.

What I want to do is to create a Callback that every `n` (e.g. `n=10`) epochs calls a function.
According to the Keras documentation (https://keras.io/callbacks/) the base class `keras.callbacks.Callback` has a property `params`.

Does this property include the current epoch? And if so, how can it be used/called?

Or is there any other good way to call a function every `n` epochs?

I had a Callback in mind that works similar as `keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` when using the argument `period=10`.

Help would be really appreciated. Thank you :)

Edit:
After quite some reading I came up with this and it seems to work (still needs to test it properly)

```
class Test1(callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epochs, logs={})
        if epochs == 10:
            print('abc') #a random function

callb = Test1()    
model = networks.compute_network(layers=layers, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, call_list=[callb])
# compute_network in my case loads all the data, trains the network, and then returns it
```

One site helped me in particular to understand Callbacks better: https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2016/07/16/keras-callbacks/

Comment: Callbacks have an `on_epoch_begin/on_epoch_end` [method](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L183). You could add `if epoch==10: do something` to the body of these methods

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't get that I can call `epochs` that simply. I was looking for it in `self.params` and `self.model`

Comment: @HMK I suggest you add this as an answer

Comment: Similar explanation here - https://www.javacodemonk.com/creating-custom-keras-callbacks-in-python-3d4f6e9b

Answer (score 3):

As @HMK said, `on_epoch_begin` and `on_epoch_end` methods provide the current epoch. For example, to apply a function every 10th epochs you can edit your custom callback like that:

```
class myCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None)
        if epoch % 10 == 0:
            your_func()
```