# How to call callback after n epochs but always in the last epoch of training?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I want to call a callback after n epochs, but always in the last epoch of training. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025269/creating-a-keras-callback-that-activates-every-n-epochs) explains how I can call the callback after n epochs.

At the moment I am using the following approach:

```py
class MyCallBack(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, log=None)

        if epoch % 10 == 0:  # <- add additional condition here
            self._do_the_stuff()
            
            
    def _do_the_stuff(self):
        print('Do the stuff')
        
        
    def on_training_end(self, logs=None):
        self._do_the_stuff()
```

Is there a simpler way where I add an additional condition to the if statement inside `on_epoch_end` and don't need `on_training_end`?

Comment: Why don't you like the approach you presented? It seems to me it is the simplest/cleanest way to to it, since your callback object does not have access to the total number of epochs.

Comment: So, there is no way to acces the total number of epochs within the callback directly (excluding the possibility of passing the number of epochs as an initialization parameter)

Comment: You can check if the dictionnary `self.params` contains the key `epochs`, if it is the case, you could use this in your if statement. If not, I do not see another clean way to do it other than the one you presented.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Ewran in the comments above, it is possible to access the total number of epochs by `self.params['epochs'].

```py
class MyCallBack(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, log=None)

        if epoch % self.epoch_freq == 0 or epoch == self.params.get('epochs', -1):
            self._do_the_stuff()
            
            
    def _do_the_stuff(self):
        print('Do the stuff')
        
        
    def on_training_end(self, logs=None):
        self._do_the_stuff()
```

If other callbacks such as `tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping` are used, I would continue to use the approach with `on_train_end`. Otherwise it is not guaranteed that the callback is called after the last epoch.